# How to get readonly access to mysql files via g+w permission 750 or 640?

Tags: mysql, permissions, datafile, unix

The `data-dir` itself has permissions `700` thereby limiting access to the `mysql` user.

I want other folks who I add to the `mysql` group to be able to read `binlogs` and download the `*.frm`, `*.MYI`, `*.MYD` files to their local computer.

My first thought is to run `chmod g+rx data-dir`.

The database directories and table/binlog files within `data-dir` have permissions with `770` / `660`. So I have to `chmod g-w` on all of those to prevent accidental tampering or removal of live data.

Unfortunately, as new `binlogs` are created, and the `create database` or `create table` command is used, the `g+w` permission is automatically added. How can I change this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found online that the environment variable `UMASK` and `UMASK_DIR` must be set, regardless of what the command `umask` will output.

One must add `export UMASK=0640` and `export UMASK=0750` to the top of their startup script, immediately before calling `mysqld_safe`.

The leading zero is important to switch to the octal numbering system.

The first thing I tried was `0027`, but that produced files with permissions `u=rw,g=w,o=rwx` so that is what prompted me to invert the permissions in the environment variable to `0750` (and `0640`) to produce the desired results.

I hope my self-answer will help a future visitor. :-)

Answer (score 1):

What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve??  `UMASK` may be the wrong approach.

The files and directories must be fully accessible by the `mysql` "user", so directories need at least 0700 and files need 0600.

If you want the "world" to be able to read them (but not write them), 0755 and 0644.  But why would you want that?  And you probably have to have `UMASK_DIR=0755` and `UMASK=644` to prevent the bottom bits from being turned off by the OS.

MySQL has access control *inside* MySQL.  This is via the `GRANT` command in MySQL.  And MySQL "users" are not the same as OS "users".  In particular, the OS 'root' and MySQL's 'root' are independent.

Comment: 755/644 would be too permissive. That is why I opted for 750 and 640 in my self-answer. (I figured it out after posting the question) *"What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve??*" When researching problems, the `binlogs` are very useful. I don't want to have to log in as root to get to them though. But if I'm going to give a user readonly access to `binlogs`, that's pretty permissive so for consistency, they might as well get the convenience of readonly access to the whole database. The main problem though, was that the files were `g=rw`, which is over doing it.

Comment: Certainly this is not for routine production use of MySQL. Certainly one would use `GRANT` features. My question was specifically regarding the permissions of the underlying files on a UNIX environment.

Comment: If your "users" can be in the same _group_ as "mysql", then 0750 and 0640 give them readonly access (the '5' and '4').  This may be the minimal way to do your unusual task.